# GitPython clone_from promting `Username for `https://github.com``

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using `GitPython` to clone git repositories on `Github.com`,

However the `git.Repo.clone_from()` is not working, and keep asking me the usename of `Github.com`

```
import git
git.Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/aligos/belajar-rust", "belajar-rust")
```

I found that this is caused by the git repository, it seems some repository requires `Username` and `Password` authenticated before cloning.

I wonder how to deal with the prompt?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/1256452 - it's technically *neither* Git *nor* Python asking for user-name and password, but rather the helper program that Git uses to obtain authenticated `https` access to GitHub. You must authenticate to gain access, but you control the *method* of authentication (ssh or https) via the URL, and having chosen a method, the next level down is generally OS-specific. (See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/33343091/1256452 if you choose to use ssh.)

Comment: @torek thanks for the hints.

Comment: @torek As you illustrated, I have to get authenticated before cloning, but in my situation (downloading many git repositories), only few of them requesting Username and Password, I can download other repositories without inputting password.

Comment: Yes, whether authentication is required (and who is allowed access) is per-GitHub-repository, as controlled by GitHub. (GitHub in turn set that based on each repository owner's request.)

Comment: Thanks@torek, I understand now.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520843/how-to-clone-from-specific-branch-from-git-using-gitpython,  it's the same case as your's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone from specific branch from Git using Gitpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520843/how-to-clone-from-specific-branch-from-git-using-gitpython)