# Clone a specific directory from git repo using Git-Python

Tags: python, git, github, git-clone, gitpython

My git repo is of more than 2GB in size. I need to clone this repo locally via python and do some updates to it. It is just enough if I clone a particular directory in it. 
How to accomplish this with git-python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone from specific branch from Git using Gitpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520843/how-to-clone-from-specific-branch-from-git-using-gitpython)